# Getting error while accessing server's jupyter notebook remotely from the local machine

Tags: python-3.x, server, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, jupyter-lab

I am getting the following error after following the steps for accessing the server's Jupyter Notebook remotely:

1. jupyter notebook --no-browser -port=8890 (Accessing Server Remotely from local machine )
2. ssh -N -L localhost:8891:localhost:8890 login@ip_address_server (On local machine terminal)
   and getting the following error:
   [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKrez.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
The error is because of the first step of the method (use --port instead of -port) :

1. jupyter notebook --no-browser -port=8890 (Accessing Server Remotely from local machine )
   Change :

jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8890 (Accessing Server Remotely from local machine )

2.ssh -N -L localhost:8891:localhost:8890 login@ip_address_server (On local machine terminal)

3. Then, run jupyter notebook on the local machine's browser (firefox or chrome): localhost:8891